# How to see stack traces in Express JS server logs?

Tags: express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

My stack includes: Nuxt (Vue), Express.js, Axios

When I make a REST call that fails, like this:

```
axios.get('api/data-test');
```

I see this in the client:

```
xhr.js:172 GET http://localhost:3000/api/data-test 500 (ReferenceError)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:172
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:11
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:53
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:68
wrap @ bind.js:9
getDataFromDb @ test.vue:21
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6911
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

Clearly something has gone pear shaped, but the server is silent.

How do I get to see the stack trace of what went wrong on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to the Express error handling documentation:

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

It explains how handle synchronous and asynchronous errors.
Basically, you need to pass your error as argument of the next() function and provide a personalized error handler or use the default one:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});
```

This code must be placed **after** all other calls to "use".

Comment: OK, that actually did work. Of course, this bit of code needs to be located in a very specific place, after all the other calls to "use". Why printing stack traces isn't just the default behavior, I'm sure I'll never know.